# Rails will_paginate ignore format when rendering with format json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm attempting to render the will_paginate html on the server so I can transplant the entire pager (and some other data) via ajax .

I've been able to use

```
view_context.will_paginate(@posts)
```

to successfully render the pager in my controller for the ajax call.

Unfortunately, when I run that using format.json, all of my links include the .json format.

```
/posts.json?page=1
/posts.json?page=2
```

when they should really be

```
/posts?page=1
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using the latest will_paginate gem then you can just create a custom link renderer like so

```
#
# lib/custom_link_renderer.rb
#
class CustomLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
  protected
  def url(page)
    page = super.gsub(".json", "")
  end
end
```

Make sure you autoload your lib directory in your application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

then you can render your pager like so

```
view_context.will_paginate(@posts, renderer: CustomLinkRenderer)
```

Hope this helps and happy coding

Comment: In retrospect, what I was trying to do turned out to be a terrible idea, but I can confirm that this does work :D Thanks Digi_Cazter